# tikz picture | path from a path?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node, tikz-path

I'm trying to generate the following, which took about 60 seconds in my favourite vector-drawing too, but I'd like some advice on how to render the same thing using tikz:

[image]

I've cobbled together a MWE (below) using tikz-picture, which 'works' (more or less', but feels like a 'kludge'. Basically, I use a 'fake second row' in a matrix of nodes (to let me draw the curved path leaving from ~middle of the path connecting N1 and N2), and a 'fake' empty node in the middle of the path connecting N1 and N2. The issue I've struggled with is -- how to draw a path from the middle of another path? I've convinced myself (perhaps in error), that you can only run a path from one node to another node. Hence, the use of 'fake, empty' nodes to get there from here.

Is there a more elegant way to handle this sort of thing? For some of my work, this kind of diagram shows up a lot, and it would be nice to work from a more general, robust approach than a bespoke kludge for each case.

Here is the MWE:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations,shapes,arrows,matrix,positioning,fit,arrows.meta}

 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{float}

 \usepackage{pgfplots}

 \begin{document}

 \textbf{phantom node \& phantom second row trick}

 \begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
   \rule[-1.85cm]{0pt}{3.5cm}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,->,shorten >=1.5pt,transform canvas={scale=1.05},line 
 width=1.0pt]
   \matrix (a) [matrix of nodes,row sep=0.5em, column sep=8em, every node/.style= 
{circle,draw,font=\normalsize\sffamily,minimum width=1.25cm,anchor=center},
 n.node/.style={font=\bf\normalsize\sffamily},
 empty.node/.style={draw=none,align=left,minimum width=1.5cm},
 fake.node/.style={draw=none,align=left,minimum width=0.0cm}]
 { |[empty.node]| & [-2em]|[n.node]|$N_1$  & [-5em]|[fake.node]| & |[n.node]|$N_2$ & [-2em]| 
[empty.node]| \\
 |[empty.node]| & [-2em] |[empty.node]| & [-5em]|[fake.node]| & |[empty.node]| & [-2em]| 
[empty.node]| \\};]
 \path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge node[above,near end] {$\epsilon g(N_1,N_2)$} (a-1-4);
 \path[>=stealth,font=\small] (a-1-2) edge node[below,near start] {$g(N_1,N_2)$} (a-1-4);
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-1) edge node [above] {$f(N_1)$} (a-1-2) ;
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-4) edge node [above] {$h(N_2)$} (a-1-5) ;
 \path[>=stealth,->,font=\small] (a-1-3) edge[out=0,in=100, bend left=22]  (a-2-4) ;
 \end{tikzpicture}
 \end{figure}

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `coordinate` on the segment between nodes and give it a name for later use. Default position is halfway, but you can adjust that with `pos=` the same as for nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, circle](n1) at (0,0) {$N_1$};
\node[draw, circle](n2) at (4,0) {$N_2$};
\draw[-stealth] (n1)--coordinate[pos=.4](m)
    node[scale=.6, below, pos=.2]{$g(N_1,N_2)$}
    node[scale=.6, above, pos=.8]{$\varepsilon g(N_1,N_2)$}
    (n2);
\draw[-stealth] (m) to[out=0, in=135] ++(1,-.5);
\draw[-stealth](n2)--node[scale=.6, above]{$h(N_2)$}++(1.5,0);
\draw[stealth-](n1)--node[scale=.6, above]{$f(N_1)$}++(-1.5,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great -- a very nice and useful extension to the first suggested 'solution'.  I tend to think of everything I draw as involving nodes and paths in a matrix, but I'm now thinking might be time to consider a different approach for some sorts of problems.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using elementary tikz.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick]
  \node[circle,draw](n1){$N_1$};
  \node[circle,draw,right=4 of n1](n2){$N_2$};
  \path[draw,<-]
     (n1) -- node[above]{\scriptsize$f(N_1)$} +(-2,0);
  \path[draw,->]
     (n1) -- node[below,pos=0.25]{\scriptsize$g(N_1,N_2)$}
             node[above,pos=0.75]{\scriptsize$\varepsilon g(N_1,N_2)$} (n2);
  \path[draw,->]
     (n2) -- node[above]{\scriptsize$h(N_2)$} +(2,0);
  \path[draw,->]
     (n1)+(1.5,0) .. controls +(1.5,0) and +(-0.4,0.3) .. +(3.5,-0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great -- and clearly, much simpler. I've tried to avoid Bezier curve-like approaches to things, but using controls definitely made the solution easier - in terms of code - provided one understands the positions.

Answer (score 0):

Combining TikZ-CD and a `pic`.

Using `sloped` and `allow upside down` the drive off arrow is always tangent to the line you place it on. Its optional argument can be used to change the appearence of the arrow (color, line width). With `drive off = flip` you can easily change the direction, other transformations are valid, too, of course.

In this case, we could also just draw a normal arrow just coming from the coordinate in the middle but the `drive off` pic allows us to place it along any line without having to worry about the correct angles as shown with an extra arrow.

---

The `bending` library is loaded so that the curved line is not changed because of the arrow tip. The calculation of positions along the path is using the original curve before the arrow tip was added.

The difference can be seen by redrawing the same path without an arrow tip:

```
\ar[ll, bend right, ultra thick, postaction={-, draw, dashed, help lines}]
```

which results in
[image]

Just loading the `bending` library will activate the [`flex` option](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#pgf/arrow:keys/flex) which already results in the line remaining how it should be:

[image]

Without the `bending` library, the [`quick` option](https://tikz.dev/tikz-arrows#pgf/arrow:keys/quick) is active and can be re-installed by

```
\tikzset{arrows={[quick]}}
```

in case you really need the speed for other curves. For nodes the difference is usually not noticeable.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, bending}
\tikzset{
  flip/.style={yscale=-1},
  pics/drive off/.style={
    /tikz/sloped, /tikz/allow upside down,
    code={\draw (0pt,0pt) .. controls +(0:.5cm) and +(135:.5cm) .. (1cm,-.5cm);}}}
\tikzcdset{
  drive off/.style={/tikz/every to/.append style={
    edge node={pic[behind path,#1]{drive off}}}},
  my diagram/.style = {
    /tikz/> = Stealth, arrows = ->, cells = {shape = circle, nodes = draw},
    /tikz/c/.style = {shape = coordinate, yshift = axis_height}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=1.75cm, my diagram]
  |[c]| \rar["f(N_1)"]
& N_1   \rar["{g(N_1,N_2)}"', dash]
& |[c]| \rar["{\varepsilon g(N_1,N_2)}", drive off=at start]
& N_2   \rar["h(N_2)"] 
        \ar[ll, bend right, drive off = red]
& |[c]|
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This is pretty slick. I can replicate, but am wondering why the start of the 'drive off' and the arc from which it originates (arc connection N2 -> N1), is not 'smoothly integrated'? Meaning , if you zoom in, the 'drive off' doesn't look like it emanates smoothly from the arc -- you can see the start of the 'drive off' separately from the arc.  Something to play with.

Comment: @JohnnyCanuck This is due to the arrow tip changing the curve slightly which is not transparent to the mechanic calculating the position along the path. Just loading the `bending` library which activates the `flex` option should solve this. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've also removed a comment about the pic inheriting all the settings from its parent path. This is not correct, at least not in this case (might be because of how TikZ-CD implement its `\ar` key). The color will not get inherited and changing the line width on the parent path will not change the line width of the pic but the size of the arrow. Weird!

Comment: Thanks. First time working with tikzcd -- how does one change the line width for *everything* in the diagram? Adding /tikz/line width=1.0pt to drive off style affects *those* arcs, but...;what about everything else? The default thickness (0.4mm?) is way to thin for my purposes. If this should be a separate question, let me know.

Comment: @JohnnyCanuck The default line width is [0.4pt (`thin`)](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#sec-15.3.1). Normally, just doing `\tikzset{thick}` for example in the preamble would be finde but TikZ-CD sets a custom line width that is derived from some line width of math mode (think `\to`) which means you will need to do something like `\tikzcdset{diagrams=thick, arrows=thick}`. Or, if you want it only to affect `my diagram`s you add `thick, arrows=thick` to that style.

Comment: Thanks -- that definitely helps, but am I correct in assuming that there is no way to have more precise control over line thickness, other than 'thick' or (the default) 'thin'? Using a standard tikzpicture, for example, I can specify whatever line width I want, that applies to *everything* in the picture. For example, \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, line width=1.05pt] applies to everything. I can also change the line width of individual arcs, or any other drawn element. But, not in tikzcd? Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: @JohnnyCanuck You can do this with TikZ-CD, too. Just use it, i.e. `diagrams = {line width =1.05pt}, arrows = {line width = 1.05pt}`. `thin`, `thick`, etc. are just shortcuts to `line width = <sth>`. See the link in my comment above.

Comment: Perfect -- many, many thanks!